# Test service from with dependencies in spock

Tags: spring, unit-testing, kotlin, spock

I am working with a kotlin and spring project, Now I am trying to do the test of some service, which has some dependencies, I am having some problems, in order to get a success test. Maybe I my design is not good enough, moreover I have problems trying to call the method from the spy object, I am getting the issue: Cannot invoke real method 'getClubhouseFor' on interface based mock object. This is my code, Could you give me any idea about what I am doing bad.

Thanks in advance!!!!
This is my code:

```
import com.espn.csemobile.espnapp.models.UID
import com.espn.csemobile.espnapp.models.clubhouse.*
import com.espn.csemobile.espnapp.services.clubhouse.AutomatedClubhouseService
import com.espn.csemobile.espnapp.services.clubhouse.ClubhouseService
import com.espn.csemobile.espnapp.services.clubhouse.StaticClubhouseService
import com.espn.csemobile.espnapp.services.clubhouse.contexts.ClubhouseContext
import com.espn.csemobile.espnapp.services.core.CoreService
import rx.Single
import spock.lang.Specification

class ClubhouseServiceImplTest extends Specification {


    StaticClubhouseService staticClubhouseService = GroovyStub()
    AutomatedClubhouseService automatedClubhouseService = GroovyStub()
    CoreService coreService =  GroovyStub()
    ClubhouseContext clubhouseContext = GroovyMock()
    Clubhouse clubHouse
    ClubhouseLogo clubhouseLogo
    ClubhouseService spy = GroovySpy(ClubhouseService)

    void setup() {
        clubhouseLogo = new ClubhouseLogo("http://www.google.com", true)
        clubHouse = new Clubhouse(new UID(), "summaryType", ClubhouseType.League, new ClubhouseLayout(), "summaryName", "MLB", clubhouseLogo, "http://www.google.com", "liveSportProp",new ArrayList<Integer>(), new ArrayList<ClubhouseSection>(),new ArrayList<ClubhouseAction>(), new HashMap<String, String>())
    }



    def "GetClubhouseFor"() {
        given:
        staticClubhouseService.getClubhouseFor(clubhouseContext) >> buildClubHouseMockService()
        // The idea here is to get different responses it depends on the class of call.
        automatedClubhouseService.getClubhouseFor(clubhouseContext ) >> buildClubHouseMockService()
        spy.getClubhouseFor(clubhouseContext) >> spy.getClubhouseFor(clubhouseContext)
        when:
        def actual = spy.getClubhouseFor(clubhouseContext)
        then:
        actual != null
    }

    def buildClubHouseMockService(){
        return Single.just(clubHouse)
    }
}
```

The next are the classes involved in the test:

```
import com.espn.csemobile.espnapp.models.clubhouse.*
import com.espn.csemobile.espnapp.services.clubhouse.contexts.ClubhouseContext
import com.espn.csemobile.espnapp.services.core.CoreService
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import org.springframework.web.context.annotation.RequestScope
import rx.Single

interface ClubhouseService {
    fun getClubhouseFor(context: ClubhouseContext): Single<Clubhouse?>
}

@Service
@RequestScope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.NO)
@Primary
class ClubhouseServiceImpl(private val clubhouseContext: ClubhouseContext,
                        private var staticClubhouseService: StaticClubhouseService,
                       private var automatedClubhouseService: AutomatedClubhouseService,
                       private val coreService: CoreService?): ClubhouseService {

    override fun getClubhouseFor(context: ClubhouseContext): Single<Clubhouse?> {
        return staticClubhouseService.getClubhouseFor(clubhouseContext).flatMap { clubhouse ->
            if (clubhouse != null) return@flatMap Single.just(clubhouse)

            return@flatMap automatedClubhouseService.getClubhouseFor(clubhouseContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all `GroovySpy` or `GroovyStub` do not make sense for Java or Kotlin classes because the special features of Groovy mocks are only available for Groovy classes. So don't expect to be able to mock constructors or static methods that way, if that was the reason for the usage. This is also documented [here](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/all_in_one.html#GroovyMocks):

> When Should Groovy Mocks be Favored over Regular Mocks? Groovy mocks should be used when the code under specification is written in Groovy *and* some of the unique Groovy mock features are needed. When called from Java code, Groovy mocks will behave like regular mocks. Note that it isn’t necessary to use a Groovy mock merely because the code under specification and/or mocked type is written in Groovy. Unless you have a concrete reason to use a Groovy mock, prefer a regular mock.

As for your problem with the spy, you cannot use a spy on an interface type. This is documented [here](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/all_in_one.html#Spies):

> A spy is always based on a real object. Hence you must provide a class type rather than an interface type, along with any constructor arguments for the type.

So either you just switch to Mock or Stub, both of which work on interface types, or you spy on the implementation class instead. In any case, my main suggestion is to read the documentation first and then try to use a new tool like Spock. My impression is that you have not used Spock before, but of course I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I haven't read enough the documentation, I have made some changes in the code and over the test, now I am using mock instead Groovy mocks.